# Error after added ng-toolkit/universal - ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I added @ng-toolkit/universal

`ng add @ng-toolkit/universal`

I had a whole load of errors so I'm building the project back up added and testing each component/feature at a time. Most things are working now, however, I seem to be stuck on one issue -

I want to preload a few assets as the app loads so I originally had this line, which works perfectly before ng-toolkit/universal in
`app.module.ts`

```
providers: [WorkService, { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: workProviderFactory, deps: [WorkService], multi: true }],
```

and in 
`WorkService.service.ts`

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {Project} from '../models/work-model';
    import * as THREE from 'three';

    @Injectable()
    export class WorkService {
      private timeout = 10000;
      private errorMessages = {
        0: 'internet-error',
        500: 'server-error',
        timeout: 'timeout-error'
      };
      private data: Project[];
    private tileTextures: any = [];
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

      getData(): any {
        return this.data;
      }


      load(): Promise<any> {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('/assets/case-studies/work.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => {
            this.data = res['work'];
            resolve(true);
          },
          msg => {
            reject(msg);
          }
        )
         .catch((err) => console.log("rejected:", err));
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error -

```
ERROR [Error]
[Error]
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
    at resolvePromise (dist/server.js:200857:31)
    at resolvePromise (dist/server.js:200814:17)
    at dist/server.js:200916:17
    at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (dist/server.js:200464:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (dist/server.js:4192:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (dist/server.js:200463:36)
    at Zone.module.exports.Zone.runTask (dist/server.js:200231:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (dist/server.js:200638:35)
    at module.exports.ZoneTask.invokeTask (dist/server.js:200543:21)
    at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (dist/server.js:200528:48)
  rejection: [Error],
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: [Error] },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the absolute path if you're using Universal e.g. `/assets/case-studies/work.json` will not work when being run on a node server. See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/858)